# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling showString

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When we use pyspark to generate analytics, we find sometimes it generates error with no details to debug. How do we go about to identifying the issue and resolving it. This is the exception shown.

```
File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 502, in show
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1310, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1060.showString.
: org.apache.spark.util.SparkFatalException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.$anonfun$relationFuture$1(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:185)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: what is the code/query that you are trying to run/execute?

Comment: Could you describe more of what set up you are running, what platform etc that will help others diagnose the problem?

Comment: Hello. Any chance you resolved this issue? Thank you!